# unknown database with mysql-connector in python

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-connector

I'm new to dealing with databases. I created a simple database in phpmyadmin and joined it with another database. Now I'm trying to access the database in python with the mysql-connector module, but python doesn't seem to be able to detect it. I've named and saved my database as the one below, but I have no idea if this even connects or can find it. I converted the DB to a .sql, but I don't know what to do with it.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='',
    database='python_sql',
    )
```

Furthermore, I have practically no knowledge of PHP, so I wasn't able to write some fancy script as some do. I see in the tutorials people get through this step no problem even when they make the program in phpmyadmin, so I don't know whats wrong with my code. When I run it, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 216, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Unknown database 'python_sql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnminton/Documents/Python/Python database internal/mysql-db.py", line 7, in <module>
    database='python_sql'
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 264, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 966, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 219, in _open_connection
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'python_sql'
```

EDIT: when I remove the 'database=python_sql' I get no error, so it seems to connect fine to my localhost

Comment: Did you provide the root password to connector and you have a spare comma after the db name.

Comment: What has your lack of PHP to do with this Python code? Also, are you sure that the database `python_sql` exists?

Answer (score -1):

in this code, you can handle most errors that happened because connect

```
from mysql.connector import errorcode
try:
  myconn = mysql.connector.connect(
      host='your host name ',
      user='username',
      passwd='Password to access',
      database='DataBase Name')
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        myconn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='1234',
        )
        mycurs = myconn.cursor()
        mycurs.execute("CREATE DATABASE ttt")
        myconn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='1234',
            database='ttt'
        )
    else:
        print(err)
else:
  myconn.close()
```

Comment: This answer may lead to unwanted results. This code creates a database called `ttt`. This might not be wanted.
I also think this does not answer the question. Also please be so kind and put more effort in answering questions. Your English is very hard to understand.
Could you please edit your answer?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)